# using >>, -, + to make a number X times the constant K for the following numbers

Tags: arithmetic, binary

if were only allowed to use >>, -, + to make a number X times the constant K
lets assume K is 17
and K is 20
how to make an expression for each

I was trying to think of ways to do this but I cant.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Operating only on $K$ itself you cannot make it larger by merely right-shifting, assuming you do not carry over bits shifted right-out. What is $1>>1$? How are $+, -$ defined? What can they operate on?

Comment: I got the answer look at it below that looks right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ is expressed in binary $$2^n\cdot a=a<<n$$ where $<<$ is the bitwise left shift operator.

$$17\cdot a=(2^4+1)\cdot a=(a<<4)+a$$ and $$20\cdot a=(2^4+2^2)\cdot a=(a<<4)+(a<<2)$$